# Left join - to many results returned

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have a challenge with a left join giving me to many results. I want to list winners in a contest. In my winners table I have id, contest, image, place, published. I appreciate any help I can get! :-)

$id returns the current contest id.

In my example winners table has only 3 rows, but returns 9 rows.

Here's my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            photocontest_winners.id, 
            photocontest_winners.contest, 
            photocontest_winners.image, 
            photocontest_winners.place, 

            photocontest_entries.id, 
            photocontest_entries.contest, 
            photocontest_entries.name, 
            photocontest_entries.title,
            photocontest_entries.image

        FROM photocontest_winners 

        LEFT JOIN photocontest_entries ON photocontest_winners.contest = photocontest_entries.contest

        WHERE photocontest_winners.contest = $id AND photocontest_winners.published = 1 
        ORDER BY photocontest_winners.place";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($row);
    echo("</pre>");

}
```

Here an example output (I don't understand why each image has int 1, 2 & 3 in "place" as i doesn't apper like that in the database.:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [contest] => 2
    [image] => dummy-item.jpg
    [place] => 1
    [name] => Daniel
    [title] => aar
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [contest] => 2
    [image] => dummy-item.jpg
    [place] => 1
    [name] => Peter
    [title] => Andet billede
)
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [contest] => 2
    [image] => dummy-item.jpg
    [place] => 1
    [name] => Lucas
    [title] => Andet billede test
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [contest] => 2
    [image] => dummy-item.jpg
    [place] => 2
    [name] => Daniel
    [title] => aar
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [contest] => 2
    [image] => dummy-item.jpg
    [place] => 2
    [name] => Peter
    [title] => Andet billede
)
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [contest] => 2
    [image] => dummy-item.jpg
    [place] => 2
    [name] => Lucas
    [title] => Andet billede test
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [contest] => 2
    [image] => dummy-item.jpg
    [place] => 3
    [name] => Daniel
    [title] => aar
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [contest] => 2
    [image] => dummy-item.jpg
    [place] => 3
    [name] => Peter
    [title] => Andet billede
)
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [contest] => 2
    [image] => dummy-item.jpg
    [place] => 3
    [name] => Lucas
    [title] => Andet billede test
)
```

contests table with sample data:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `photocontest_contests`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `photocontest_contests`;
CREATE TABLE `photocontest_contests` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prize_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intro` text,
  `prizes` text,
  `rules` text,
  `privacy_policy` text,
  `time_start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `published` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
--  Records of `photocontest_contests`
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `photocontest_contests` VALUES ('1', 'Contest 1', 'dummy-cat.jpg', 'dummy-prize.jpg', 'EOS 5D Mark III er et fullframe digitalt spejlreflekskamera med 22,3 Megapixel, autofokus med 61 punkter samt 6 bps kontinuerlig optagelse. Optag Full HD-film i høj kvalitet, og hav fuld manuel kontrol over alt lige fra billedhastighed til lyd.', '<div class=\"row\">\n                <div class=\"prize odd\">\n                 <div class=\"prize-desc\"><h3>1. Præmie</h3><p>EOS 5D Mark III er et fullframe digitalt spejlreflekskamera med 22,3 Megapixel, autofokus med 61 punkter samt 6 bps kontinuerlig optagelse. Optag Full HD-film i høj kvalitet, og hav fuld manuel kontrol over alt lige fra billedhastighed til lyd.</p></div>\n                 <div class=\"prize-image\">\n                       <img src=\"images/dummy-prize.jpg\" alt=\"\" />\n                   </div>\n                    <div class=\"clr\"></div>\n             </div>\n            </div>\n            <div class=\"row\">\n               <div class=\"prize even\">\n                    <div class=\"prize-desc\"><h3>2. Præmie</h3><p>EOS 5D Mark III er et fullframe digitalt spejlreflekskamera med 22,3 Megapixel, autofokus med 61 punkter samt 6 bps kontinuerlig optagelse. Optag Full HD-film i høj kvalitet, og hav fuld manuel kontrol over alt lige fra billedhastighed til lyd.</p></div>\n                 <div class=\"prize-image\">\n                       <img src=\"images/dummy-prize.jpg\" alt=\"\" />\n                   </div>\n                    <div class=\"clr\"></div>\n             </div>\n            </div>\n            <div class=\"row\">\n               <div class=\"prize odd\">\n                 <div class=\"prize-desc\"><h3>3. Præmie</h3><p>EOS 5D Mark III er et fullframe digitalt spejlreflekskamera med 22,3 Megapixel, autofokus med 61 punkter samt 6 bps kontinuerlig optagelse. Optag Full HD-film i høj kvalitet, og hav fuld manuel kontrol over alt lige fra billedhastighed til lyd.</p></div>\n                 <div class=\"prize-image\">\n                       <img src=\"images/dummy-prize.jpg\" alt=\"\" />\n                   </div>\n                    <div class=\"clr\"></div>\n             </div>\n            </div>', 'rules', 'privacy', '2015-05-12 14:18:02', '2015-05-28 14:18:07', '1'), ('2', 'Contest 2', 'dummy-cat.jpg', 'dummy-prize.jpg', '2 EOS 5D Mark III er et fullframe digitalt spejlreflekskamera med 22,3 Megapixel, autofokus med 61 punkter samt 6 bps kontinuerlig optagelse. Optag Full HD-film i høj kvalitet, og hav fuld manuel kontrol over alt lige fra billedhastighed til lyd.', '<div class=\"row\">\n                <div class=\"prize odd\">\n                 <div class=\"prize-desc\"><h3>1. Præmie</h3><p>EOS 5D Mark III er et fullframe digitalt spejlreflekskamera med 22,3 Megapixel, autofokus med 61 punkter samt 6 bps kontinuerlig optagelse. Optag Full HD-film i høj kvalitet, og hav fuld manuel kontrol over alt lige fra billedhastighed til lyd.</p></div>\n                 <div class=\"prize-image\">\n                       <img src=\"images/dummy-prize.jpg\" alt=\"\" />\n                   </div>\n                    <div class=\"clr\"></div>\n             </div>\n            </div>\n            <div class=\"row\">\n               <div class=\"prize even\">\n                    <div class=\"prize-desc\"><h3>2. Præmie</h3><p>EOS 5D Mark III er et fullframe digitalt spejlreflekskamera med 22,3 Megapixel, autofokus med 61 punkter samt 6 bps kontinuerlig optagelse. Optag Full HD-film i høj kvalitet, og hav fuld manuel kontrol over alt lige fra billedhastighed til lyd.</p></div>\n                 <div class=\"prize-image\">\n                       <img src=\"images/dummy-prize.jpg\" alt=\"\" />\n                   </div>\n                    <div class=\"clr\"></div>\n             </div>\n            </div>\n            <div class=\"row\">\n               <div class=\"prize odd\">\n                 <div class=\"prize-desc\"><h3>3. Præmie</h3><p>EOS 5D Mark III er et fullframe digitalt spejlreflekskamera med 22,3 Megapixel, autofokus med 61 punkter samt 6 bps kontinuerlig optagelse. Optag Full HD-film i høj kvalitet, og hav fuld manuel kontrol over alt lige fra billedhastighed til lyd.</p></div>\n                 <div class=\"prize-image\">\n                       <img src=\"images/dummy-prize.jpg\" alt=\"\" />\n                   </div>\n                    <div class=\"clr\"></div>\n             </div>\n            </div>', 'rules', 'privacy', '2015-05-12 14:18:02', '2015-05-12 14:18:07', '1');
COMMIT;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Entries table with sample data

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `photocontest_entries`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `photocontest_entries`;
CREATE TABLE `photocontest_entries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contest` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `published` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
--  Records of `photocontest_entries`
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `photocontest_entries` VALUES ('1', '2', 'Daniel', 'my@email.com', '12345678', 'aar', '', 'dummy-item.jpg', '1'), ('2', '1', 'Hans', 'my@email.com', '12345678', 'Mit Billede', 'Dette er en fed beskrivelse', 'dummy-item.jpg', '1'), ('3', '2', 'Peter', 'my@email.com', '12345678', 'Andet billede', 'Dette er en fed beskrivelse', 'dummy-item.jpg', '1'), ('4', '2', 'Lucas', 'my@email.com', '12345678', 'Andet billede test', 'beskrivelse', 'dummy-item.jpg', '1'), ('5', '1', 'Ditte', 'my@email.com', '12345678', 'Billede titel', 'Anden beskrivelse', 'dummy-item.jpg', '1');
COMMIT;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Winners table with sample data:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `photocontest_winners`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `photocontest_winners`;
CREATE TABLE `photocontest_winners` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contest` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `place` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

-- ----------------------------
--  Records of `photocontest_winners`
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `photocontest_winners` VALUES ('1', '2', '1', '1', '1'), ('4', '2', '3', '2', '1'), ('5', '2', '4', '3', '1');
COMMIT;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Looks like its one-to-many relation and for each `photocontest_winners` there many many entry in `photocontest_entries` and with left join its returning all the matching records. Better would be to provide some sample data and expected result of out the sample data.

Comment: This is not about the problem you asked about... I suggest renaming the fields in the query. When you have to fields with the same name, you only get one value. So, you can do something like: `photocontest_winners.id as winner_id` in the select to rename it and not overwrite it with the second instance of id.

Comment: You probably need to also join on the `image` field, but we really need to see some sample data, and the structure of your tables to give a better answer.

Comment: I have updated my question with sql dump with structure and sample data for all my tables (3)

Comment: @Vex you hit the nail on the head :-) a LEFT JOIN like this solved my problem: LEFT JOIN photocontest_entries ON photocontest_winners.contest = photocontest_entries.contest AND photocontest_winners.image = photocontest_entries.id

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more comprehensive if you would also tell us the name of the columns for every table and 1-2 entry rows for them. After this i can make an idea about what could go wrong.

My first guess is that the key you are using to left join

> JOIN photocontest_entries ON photocontest_winners.contest = photocontest_entries.contest

it's not unique. In one of the tables your key, **photocontest_winners.contest** has several matches to the others table records photocontest_entries.contest**strong text**. Or the other way arround...

Comment: I have updated my question with sql dumps from the 3 tables with sample data in it :-)

Answer (score 0):

As written, your query will produce EVERY Winner and any matching contest entries for the specific contentes. It will also return winners for that contest id without contest entries.

As someone else stated, because you are not using column aliases... if the record returned was tied to an entry, you are seeing that id value in the array.

try writting your query like this

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            photocontest_winners.id, 
            photocontest_winners.contest, 
            photocontest_winners.image, 
            photocontest_winners.place, 

            photocontest_entries.id as `entry_id`, 
            photocontest_entries.contest, 
            photocontest_entries.name, 
            photocontest_entries.title,
            photocontest_entries.image

        FROM photocontest_winners 

        LEFT JOIN photocontest_entries ON photocontest_winners.contest = photocontest_entries.contest

        WHERE photocontest_winners.contest = $id AND photocontest_winners.published = 1 
        ORDER BY photocontest_winners.place";
```

Comment: Made no difference using column alias on entry_id :-(

Answer (score 0):

@Vex provided the answer - I had to add image id to the join.

```
LEFT JOIN photocontest_entries ON
    photocontest_winners.contest = photocontest_entries.contest AND
    photocontest_winners.image = photocontest_entries.id
```

This solved my problem.